# Why the solution of this problem can be written in this way?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider this kind of problem

$$ v_{tt} + \Delta v + v_{t} = 0, $$

with $ x\in R^{n}, t\geq 0 $ and initial data

\begin{equation} 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
 v(x,0) = \phi(x)  \\
 v_{t}(x,0) = \psi(x)
\end{array}
 \right.
\end{equation}

I read that the solution can be written in this way:

$$ v(x,t) = K_1\ast \psi + K_2\ast \phi. $$ 
Could anyone explain me why it is true?

Comment: Do you know what the convolution of two functions is?

Comment: Yes, sure i know.

Comment: I bet your material will say something about $K_1$ and $K_2$.
Think that solutions to this problem, in a way, integrate the initial data yielded by $\phi$ and $\psi$, and that way is a convolution.

Comment: Do you mean $u$ or $v$ ?

Comment: It was v, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the principle of superposition.

If the initial conditions are

$$\begin{equation} 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
 v(x,0) = \delta(x-x_0)  \\
 v_{t}(x,0) = 0
\end{array}
 \right.
\end{equation}$$

or

$$\begin{equation} 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
 v(x,0) = 0 \\
 v_{t}(x,0) = \delta(x-x_0) 
\end{array}
 \right.
\end{equation}$$

you get some solutions

$$v_\phi(x,t;x_0)$$ and $$v_\psi(x,t;x_0).$$

Then to get the solution corresponding to the general initial conditions, we convolve with $\phi$ and $\psi$ (the convolution is a sum of elementary solutions), and add both.

$$v(x,t)=v_\phi(x,t;x_0)\star\phi(x_0)+v_\psi(x,t;x_0)\star\psi(x_0).$$

The integration is made on $x_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is still not so clear fo me.

Comment: Please, could you explain why we convolve with $\phi$ and $\psi?$

Comment: @C.Bishop: because $\delta(x-x_0)\star\phi(x)=\phi(x_0)$