# Solution of the damped wave equation written as convolution

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, convolution

Consider this kind of problem

$$ v_{tt} + \Delta v + v_{t} = 0, $$

with $ x\in R^{n}, t\geq 0 $ and initial data

\begin{equation} 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
 v(x,0) = \phi(x)  \\
 v_{t}(x,0) = \psi(x)
\end{array}
 \right.
\end{equation}

I read that the solution can be written in this way:

$$ v(x,t) = K_1\ast \psi + K_2\ast \phi, $$

where $ K_1 $ and $ K_2 $ denote some kernels (as my notes said).

Could anyone explain me why the solution can be written in this way?

In a [past question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3258574/418542), @Yves Daoust explained to me that it is a consequence of the superposition principle and the fact that $ \delta $ is the unit of the convolution product, but it is still not clear for me.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'why (can) the solution be written this way'? It comes straight from Fourier transforming the PDE.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the Fourier transform, as @Mattos' comment suggests to you. Formally taking the spatial FT of the PDE, we get the ODE $$\hat{v}_{tt}(\xi,t)+\hat{v}_t(\xi,t)-|\xi|^2 \hat{v}(\xi,t)=0,$$ subject to the conditions $\hat{v}(\xi,0)=\hat{\phi}(\xi),$ and $\hat{v}_t(\xi,0) =\hat{\psi}(\xi).$ Solve this ODE to find $\hat{v}(\xi,t)$, then try to express the inverse transform using convolutions; this will give you your solution $v(x,t)$. I'll leave this for you to try out yourself.